# Trying to create an Accordion style FAQ

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have tried so many different types of Accordions for my FAQ, but not successful.  I have a list FAQ with the Title renamed as Question and added a multi-line text Answer.

I have the following script and I'm getting the data, but accordion is not a function

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     getListItems();
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 });

 function getListItems() {
     $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
        "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$select=Title,Answer",
         method: "GET",
         headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
         },
         success: function(data) {
         $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
             $("#accordion").append("<h3>" + item.Title + "</h3><div><p>" + item.Answer + "</p></div>");
         });
         var icons = {
             header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
             activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
         };
         $("#accordion").accordion();
         },
         error: function(data) {},
         async: false
     });
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="accordion">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to the jQuery library in the code. Modify the code as below to make it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jq(document).ready(function() {
    getListItems(); 
});
function getListItems() {
    jq.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$select=Title,Answer",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jq.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
                jq("#accordion").append("<h3>" + item.Title + "</h3><div><p>" + item.Answer + "</p></div>");
            });
            var icons = {
                header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
            };
            jq("#accordion").accordion();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }        
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied your code and still does not work.  I get the data, but no accordion.  I get an error accordion is not a function.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work fine in Chrome, but it does not work in IE11.  The two issues I have is JQuery not found (accessing external jquery I assume).  Can't load the css for incorrect mime type, IE11 wants type=text\css, but Chrome wants text/css.  Not certain how to solve this, but put both in.  :(    Lastly, the following error in IE: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'.  but works in Chrome.

Comment: Add the code into script editor web part to check if it works.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I use a Script Editor or a content Web part.  Same results.